# hammer.js - how to register a "hold" event without propagating a "click" event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I want to register a hold event, but "skip" the logic behind the "click" event on this element and its parents... how do I do that?

Test case (please feel free to fork & edit): http://codepen.io/muszek/pen/detAK

Use case: User holds on a #foo box to open up a #bar dialog with options for that element. Clicking anywhere (but on the #bar) closes the #bar. Currently, holding #foo opens up #bar, but immediately closes it when the button is released.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iLFqK ??

Comment: @RobertRozas I think they want to keep the click functionality for regular clicks, but not have it fire after a hold event.

Comment: @Robert Rozas: Anthony Grist is right, I want this user action to only trigger "hold" (and not the click), while I still want to have click happen when it's not the hold event.

Comment: Not sure if there's a more elegant way, but you could do it like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjoAw

Comment: @AnthonyGrist now i get it...btw nice solution.

Comment: @Anthony: thanks. I ended up doing what Simon suggested, but your solution works, too.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist thanks, you save  me a lot of time.

Comment: I have had alot of luck with fastclick, https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hammer.js doesn't really handle the native events. So here you should listen for the `tap` event rather than the `click`.

I don't think a tap event is triggered if the gesture is a `hold`, but if it does, just call `e.gesture.stopDetect();` to prevent multiple gesture type of being triggered. (for example, this is often use to prevent `release` event from being triggered after a `swipe`)

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent a native click being fired. What you should do is listen for 'tap' instead of 'click'. Hammer.js defines hold as a tap that lasts more than a certain amount of time.

If you are not listening for 'click' at all, but want to prevent an href or a button from being fired, forget it. Change the button for a div and the href for a normal text, style them  so they look as before and now listen for 'tap' on them.

Answer (score -1):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPVXrP

Wrap inside parent `<div>`.